# Why can I not define member functions that have been forward declared in the same file?

Tags: c++, xcode

I am working on a project, and I have used Xcode in the past, and it has been "acting up" lately (might be me). The following code is a test code for this question (not my project).

(Assume that all lexical/preprocessing/namespace directives are all there.)

*In Foo.hpp*

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo();
};

Foo::Foo() {
    cout << "constructive" << endl;
}
```

Now, if I run a main that constructs a Foo object, it gives a linker error of duplicate symbol. How should I fix this?

Comment: It's not Xcode that's acting up.

Comment: Haha, that came from a little joke that Xcode does weird things once in a while.

Answer (score 2):

The quick and dirty fix is to either write

`inline Foo::Foo(){`

or fully define the function in the class definition:

```
public:
    Foo(){cout << "constructive" << endl;}
```

The better fix is to ensure that the constructor definition is only compiled in exactly one translation unit; i.e. put it in a source file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function as inline:

```
class Foo {
public:
    inline Foo();
};
```

or put it in a .cpp file, to ensure that it is defined in only one translation unit:

```
// foo.cpp
Foo::Foo() {
    cout << "constructive" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Oh, looks like I found the answer. All I did is delete Foo.cpp and it solved the problem. Also, I could have put the definitions in the .cpp file, but sending that to people isn't the best.

My new question is why does this work?

Comment: *this means _the first solution_.

Comment: That will work until another translation unit `#include`s `Foo.hpp`